# Restar fechas con formato datetime64[ns] de un dataframe en python 3 con Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Tengo dos columnas con fechas en formato datetime64[ns] en un dataframe de Pandas y me gustaría poder **restar las dos fechas**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito **restar la columna 1 con la columna 2** para obtener una edad.
El problema lo resolví de la siguiente manera

```py
df['dias'] =  (df['1'] - df['2']).dt.days ### devuelve una serie con los dias en formato int64
df['edad2'] = df['dias']/365.2425 ### transformado en año diviendo por el año gregoriano
df['edad2'] = df['edad2'].astype(int) ## convirtiendo a entero
df['edad2']
```

Ejecutando el código anteriormente señalado logro resolver el problema, ahora mi duda es ¿Existirá otra forma de obtener la solución?  ¿Hay una forma más directa o elegante?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues hay muchas formas, pero la que tú has hecho está bien. Te dejo aquí otra

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

rdelta = relativedelta()
In [109]: rdelta.years
Out[109]: 11
```

Lo que tú has hecho está bien, si quieres que quede más elegante puedes crearte una función y llamarla cuando quieras, aplicandola al dataframe con las builtin functions **apply** o **map** .

```
def date_diff(date1, date2):
    return (date1 -  date2).days /365.2425

In[115]: date_diff(datetime.datetime.today(), datetime.datetime(2008, 4, 24))
Out[115]: 11.340410822946398
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Rubiales alberto, tu segunda opción me sirvió mucho para encontrar una solución más elegante.

Comment: Me alegro! de nada :)